# How can I use webpack without React in this case?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, webpack, jsx

I created a simple file like this:

```
function Welcome() {
  return <h1>Hello, World</h1>;
}
```

However when I run webpack it states:

```
Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

which asks me to add react.

I would like to develop pure JavaScript / JSX / XML / HTML / CSS and use webpack to bundle my functions and classes without React.

How can I do this?

Why does webpack need React for my simple function?

Comment: Because your function is invalid javascript. `return '<h1>Hello, World</h1>';` return a string.

Comment: Because it's called [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html), it's neither a string nor HTML. If you want to use pure js, html, css. Don't use JSX, use `.html` file and bundle js and inject script tag in the HTML.

Comment: I want to use JSX.  JXS is a language that is not tied to only being used with React.  That is why the error message is odd.  They are two separate things.

Answer (score 1):

You probably still need `@babel/preset-react` for your use case. This preset is in fact not limited to handling react JSX, it can handle JSX in general.

You need to modify options to fit your need. I copy-paste from [the doc](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react) the following. Notice the `"pragma": "dom"` and `"pragmaFrag": "DomFrag"` part.

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "pragma": "dom", // default pragma is React.createElement (only in classic runtime)
        "pragmaFrag": "DomFrag", // default is React.Fragment (only in classic runtime)
        "throwIfNamespace": false, // defaults to true
        "runtime": "classic" // defaults to classic
        // "importSource": "custom-jsx-library" // defaults to react (only in automatic runtime)
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

With above config, your code will be transformed into:

```js
function Welcome() {
  return dom("h", null, "Hello, World");
}
```

And if you use fragment like:

```
function Welcome() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>hello</div>
      <div>world</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

It'll be transformed into:

```js
function Welcome() {
  return dom(
    DomFrag, null, [
      dom("div", null, "hello"),
      dom("div", null, "world")
    ]
  )
}
```

Of course, you'll need to provide and manually import `dom` and `DomFrag` in your source file.

Comment: Thanks, I found this useful, but there should be a webpack "device" made specifically for jsx?  That is a question.  It is odd that webpack tells me I need React for JSX as if they are tied together.

Comment: _There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things._ -- Phil Karlton

Comment: Historically they were tied together. JSX is “invented” by React team. But later it’s used by other projects.

Comment: Thanks.  Is your function `dom()` part of the React library?

Comment: No. I said it in the answer: _you'll need to provide and manually import `dom` and `DomFrag` in your source file._ Those two are just random variable names. You’ll need you bring your own lib.

Comment: You can mark my answer as accepted if it helps you.